# QML naming confussion

Tags: reference, qml, naming

I have a basic question about naming components in QML files. I have read that the top element should always get the id *root* and *parent* is always the reference to the next element above it.

I have a two qml files, one with a `ListView` and one with the listview delegate

**Userlogon.qml**

```js
Item {
    id: root
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    property var password: ['0', '1', '2', '3']
    property int selectedField : mill.selectedIndex
    property int selectedUser : 0
    property string p_background: configuration.getColor(Colors.ContentBackground)

    ColumnLayout { anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle { id: userlist; Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true; Layout.preferredHeight: 300; color: p_background
            ColumnLayout { anchors.fill: parent
                ListView { Layout.fillWidth: true;  Layout.fillHeight: true
                    model: user.model
                    currentIndex: 1
                    onCurrentIndexChanged: { console.log("currentIndex changed") }
                    header: UserItemDelegate { p_index: -1; p_name: "Benutzeranmeldung"; p_icon: "password"; p_isHeader: true }
                    delegate: UserItemDelegate { p_index: index; p_name: name; p_icon: icon; p_isHeader: false }
                    spacing: 20
                }
            }
        }
```

**UserItemDelegate.qml**

```js
Item {
    id: root
    height: configuration.getSize(Sizes.ListItemHeight)
    width: parent.width
    property int p_index
    property string p_name
    property string p_icon
    property bool p_isHeader
    property bool p_isSelected: root.ListView.view.currentIndex == p_index
    property string p_color: configuration.getColor(p_isHeader ? Colors.ListItemDisabled : (p_isSelected ? Colors.ListItemSelected : Colors.ListItemDefault)) 
    
    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true; color: p_color
        RowLayout { anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter; 
            Image { Layout.leftMargin: 10; sourceSize.height: root.height * 0.6; source: "image://iconprovider/" + p_icon }
            Label { Layout.leftMargin: 10; text: p_name }
        }
        MouseArea{ enabled: !p_isHeader; anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: { root.ListView.view.currentIndex = p_index; } } 
    }
}
```

With *root.Listview.view.currentIndex* I can access the listview in the parent *UserLogon.qml* although *root* is the id of the current item?

And is it possible to access e.g. a timer defined in UserLogon.qml from the delegate. If so how would the referencing be?

Comment: I find that the usage of `root.ListView.view` in your delegate rather ugly. Instead, to improve readability, I usually declare `property ListView listView: ListView.view` at the top of my delegate which gives convenient access to your `ListView` from within your delegate. Usage of that property looks tidy, e.g. `listView.currentIndex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to name every root object "root". I don't know where you read that, but you can use whatever name makes sense to you.

When you call `root.ListView.view.currentIndex`, the `root` in that case is the id of the delegate, not the list. QML's scoping rules guarantee that. The `ListView.view` attached property then allows you to reference back to the list without needing its id.

Your timer question is unclear. In general, yes you can have access to the ListView's properties from the delegate, but you should usually do it the other way around. The ListView should reference the delegate's properties. The reason is that you may have a need to use that delegate somewhere else and you don't necessarily want it tightly coupled with the ListView in that case. Here's an example:

MyList.qml

```
ListView {
    id: contactList

    Timer {
        id: backgroundTimer
        interval: 3000
        running: true
    }

    model: 5
    delegate: MyDelegate {
        width: contactList.width

        // ListView binds the delegate's 'timedOut' property to something
        timedOut: backgroundTimer.running
    }
}
```

MyDelegate.qml

```
Rectangle {
    id: contact
    property bool timedOut: false

    height: 30
    radius: height / 2
    color: timedOut ? "red" : "blue"
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I just want to add that there is also [ListView.isCurrentItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-listview.html#isCurrentItem-attached-prop) so there is no need to compare indices.

Comment: Right, I had intended to mention that too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. So in this case it is the property of MyDelegate.qml as delegate that it gets a link back to its listview. Thats clear now. 
The question with the timer was misleading, sorry. What I want to ask was if it is possible to access elements of a parent view from a chield view regardless whether the child view is used as a delegate. Or is that generally bad style.

Comment: Yes, a child can access its direct parent's properties by using `parent.someProp`, or if you use the id, like `someObjectId.someOtherProp`. It's common to access things like `parent.width` or `parent.height`. But if the child is in a separate file from the parent, I don't recommend referencing anything outside that file as it creates a coupling. Am I answering your question?